# NSXMLParserErrorMessage internal error: Huge input lookup

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, nsxmlparser

I have an IOS app where I need to parse an xml file and I've been working with NSXMLParser. I have some xml data that about 8kbytes and Im getting this error, but Im parsing smaller files without an issue. I've tried searching and I couldn't find anyone else with this problem in IOS. Is this a limitation of NSXMLParser and I need to use a different library or is there some property that has to be set to allow for larger data?

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
Here is the file exactly as I'm retrieving from my web service: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3436w653reyybpb/File.xml

Here is the code Im using:

```
// XML.m
- (id)parseXml:(NSData *)data
{
    NSXMLParser *xml = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
    xml.delegate = self;
    results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    error = nil;
    [xml parse];
    if (error) return error;
    return results;
}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI: (NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    [results addObject:attributeDict];
}
- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError
{
    error = parseError;
}
```

The code isn't even reaching the didStartElement delegate method, it's just going right to the  parseErrorOccured. The data thats being passed is the file contents that I supplied.

Comment: You did not include the error message. It may also be helpful to include some code.

Comment: 8KB is not large, there is probably some other problem, show some code.

Comment: The title is  the exact error I'm receiving.

Comment: Agreed, 8KB really is not that large. Would you be able to upload the XML somewhere where we could take a look at it?

Comment: I supplied a file with the xml info and the code Im using. Thanks

Comment: How are you getting the NSData that is passed to parseXml?  If you are using NSURLConnection delegate methods, are you sure you have the _complete_ NSData before processing it?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495836/intermittent-json-parser-failure-for-unescaped-control-character for what I mean.

Comment: @AnnaKarenina, Yes Im passing an MSMutableData to store the data from the NSURLConnection didReceiveData delegate, and Im doing "appendData:data" and calling the parse method from connectionDidFinishLoading. The file that I provided was actually cut and pasted from the debug session. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
```

specifies that it is utf-16 but it is actually utf-8

Comment: Im sorry, it looks like when I created the file there was a line feed in the beginning that I didn't notice but the actual data coming from the web service does not have the line feed in the beginning. I updated the file in the dropbox.

Comment: There is still a parsing error: "Plist parse error: Unexpected character „ at line 1". Since there are no newline characters in the file it is hard to tell where the error is.

Comment: That was it, now I just need to figure out why my web service is defaulting to utf-16. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Brian When I have network problems I always go to Charles Proxy to see what is really happening.

Answer (score 2):

As Zaph said, the issue is that it is not utf-16. In the future, if the `NSXMLParser` error message is not clear enough, you can try running this through `xmllint` at the Terminal command line. In this case, it reports:

```
$ xmllint File.xml 
File.xml:1: parser error : Document labelled UTF-16 but has UTF-8 content
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><Response Error=""><RX RxNumber="11684600
                                     ^
```

Comment: Thats a useful tool, I'll definitly be using that in the future, thanks